# Grub does not see second operating system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, uefi

I just installed Lubuntu 14.04 on a desktop computer. The Computer has two hard drives, one of them contains WindowsXP and one of them does contain Lubuntu. The idea is to have an offline XP and an online Lubuntu in dual boot. There are reasons for this, and I know that the support for XP is down.

So what happened: I installed Lubuntu and was already wondering why it did not offer to replace Windows or something. So I manually chose the second hard drive and now I can boot either windows or Lubuntu. But since the user of this computer is not a techie, I want him to choose the OS by using grub, not the boot manager that comes up when you press F11 at the right time. But when I press Shift to force Grub to show up, it does not detect WindowsXP in any way.

I tried to use the grub-customizer, but I haven't seen an option to manually add the entry to WindowsXP.

How can I offer grub with options to load Ubuntu OR WindowsXP?

Some Details that may be important:

- It's an UEFI System, but as far as I can see everything like SecureBoot etc. is disabled.
- When I booted from the USB drive, I had two Options: USB and UEFI. I first trief USB, but it didn't boot, so I chose UEFI.
- When Installing, Lubuntu did not offer to replace Windows.
- On Ubuntu installation I chose to install the Bootloader on /dev/sdb. I did it always like this when I did on my old BIOS computer, and it always worked with two hard drives and everthing (windows7, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by accident. I installed all updates, which apparently fixed it. I did it because not all (german) language files were installed, so some applications were still in english. Probably there were also other parts missing, which caused my problem.

As far as I know those parts are missing so Lubuntu still fits on a single disk.